# Preventing downward traversal in jQuery once matches are found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I'm looking to use a selector which will stop traversing downward once a match is found while still traversing through siblings. Consider the following:

```
<ul>
  <li class='foo'>
    <ul>
      <li  class='bar'>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='baz'>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When using the selector `$('ul li')`, jQuery will return `.foo`, `.bar`, and `.baz`. Ideally, I want a selector which only has `.foo` and `.baz`.

My only thoughts would be to:

1) Traverse back up looking for `$(selected).parents('ul ul')` as a method for exclusion

2) Step through the heiarchy one child at a time and to stop traversal once a match is found.

3) Use the $.not() method to exclude `ul li ul li` like `$('ul li').not('ul li ul li')`

All of these solutions seem inelegant and slow since they require multiple invocations of jQuery and are pretty far removed from native DOM methods (namely `document.querySelectorAll`). Normally, i'd just go with #3 and call it a day, but I'm developing for an embedded system where cpu cycles are at a premium and chaining jQuery invocations could potentially lead to degraded performance.

Any thoughts?

Edit: The example given is just an abstraction of a possible tree structure I would be searching. The use case is to search for the closest match on a page as part of a keyboard navigation library. Since layouts differ in structure, I can't expect the matches to be direct descendants.

Comment: Learn about the `>` selector `$("ul>li")` Only issue is you would have to filter out the inner ul...if you had a class on the outside there would be easier.

Comment: I don't want to use `>` because I don't expect matches to always be a direct descendant. For example I might have the top level `li` wrapped in a div so that matches would be more difficult to make.

Comment: Makes no sense on what you are looking for...what is the rules for a match.

Comment: I'm looking for the first instance of a match when traversing down the dom. The issue i'm trying to avoid is matching recursive matches which aren't relevant in my algorithm.

Comment: Anyway you look at it, it is going to be expensive. Basically it is going to involve a loop of some sort.

Comment: Was it something like this you were after, before the site went into read only freaking mode? http://jsfiddle.net/c2bN5/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem will require JavaScript, and your first and third ideas are where I see you finding your answer.

Just to clarify, CSS (and jQuery) selectors are interpreted from right to left. When you create a selector, the rightmost selector (the key selector) is the ultimate one you match. The browser will find the key selector, then search up (/backwards) the document until it finds a match or exhausts possible matches.

There is currently no parent CSS selector to do this the other way.

Here are samples of ways to get the behavior you're looking for with jQuery: http://jsbin.com/jazax/2/

You can get all `li` contained in a `ul` then do something if there are no `li` parent elements.

```
$("ul li").each(function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.parents("li").length) 
    {
      $this.prepend(":)");
    }

});
```

You can

```
$("ul li").not("li ul li").each(function () {

  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prepend(":)");

});
```

Or simplify that even further to reduce the number of selectors jQuery needs to match against:

```
$("ul li").not("li li").each(function () {

  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prepend("3");

});
```

Finally, here is a sample demonstrating a performance comparison. http://jsperf.com/downwardtraverseso

Comment: I found a 2-3 times faster method and added it to niko's tests: http://jsperf.com/downwardtraverseso/3. Long story short, start with `document.querySelectorAll("li")`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here : http://jsbin.com/hefeb/1/edit

```
$(function(){

  $('ul>li').text('yo');



});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $items = $('ul').children();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to output the class on the li's, so there is only one dom interaction:

```
$('li.important-link')
```

and call it a day.

Comment: two answers? what about editing the one you had already posted?

Answer (score 0):

The pure "catch-all-LI" JS selector is multiple times faster than all jQuery solutions:

```
var arr = document.querySelectorAll("li");
```

Even though you have to do something like this:

```
var c = arr.length,
    selected = new Array(c);
while (arr[--c]) {
  if (! $(arr[c]).closest("li").length) selected.push(arr[c]);
}
```

And, to piggyback on @niko's tests, you'll see it's 2-3 times faster overall: http://jsperf.com/downwardtraverseso/3